# substituting a string in place of variable in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, scripting

I pass a string as an argument to a shell script. and the shell script should tell me if the passed argument is a variable

something like this

```
if [ ! -z ${$1} ] ; then  
echo yes! $1 is a variable and its value is ${$1}  
fi
```

but this gives me bad substitution err..

I definitely know i'm missing something.. help me out!

Eg usage:

```
$ myscript.sh HOME  
yes! HOME is a variable and its value is /home/raj
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for this is:

```
${!VAR}
```

Example:

```
$ function hello() { echo ${!1}; }
$ hello HOME
/home/me
```

Comment: Nice! Is there a way to use this for assignment, i.e. some replacement for `eval $1=foo` ?

Comment: See this article for variations on that: [Indirect assignment](http://bashify.com/?Useful_Techniques:Indirect_Variables:Indirect_Assignment)

Comment: @Mat Good stuff. But this is even better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13717788/27862 ;)

Answer (score 1):

Found it here:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/bash-how-to-get-variable-name-from-variable-274718/

All you should do:

```
if [ ! -z ${!1} ]; then
    echo yes $1 is a variable and its value is ${!1}
fi
```