# Creating a string variable name from the value of another string

Tags: bash, unix

In my bash script I have two variables `CONFIG_OPTION` and `CONFIG_VALUE` which contain string `VENDOR_NAME` and `Default_Vendor` respectively.

I need to create a variable with name `$CONFIG_OPTION` ie `VENDOR_NAME` and assign the value in `CONFIG_VALUE` to newly created variable.

How I can do this?

I tried

```
$CONFIG_OPTION=$CONFIG_VALUE
```

But I am getting an error on this line as

```
'./Build.bash: line 137: VENDOR_NAME="Default_Vendor": command not found'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Though this question has not been asked the exact same way, there are multiple answers, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7776409/27862

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I know that nobody will mention it, so here I go. You can use `printf`!

```
#!/bin/bash

CONFIG_OPTION="VENDOR_NAME"
CONFIG_VALUE="Default_Vendor"

printf -v "$CONFIG_OPTION" "%s" "$CONFIG_VALUE"

# Don't believe me?
echo "$VENDOR_NAME"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for a rather surprising one... [sadly, I don't understand how this works] :)

Comment: You can read `help printf`. The `-v` option to `printf` means that it should assign the formated string to the variable the name of which is given just after the `-v` option.

Comment: This does not appear to work in at least some shells (e.g., ash shell). (Although question was specifically for Bash, so it's not a big deal.)

Comment: I've looked at a few man pages for printf(1) & printf(3) and haven't seen a description of the "-v" flag

Comment: @iletras: `-v` is a switch for Bash's _builtin_ `printf`. The documentation is hence found by either: 1. typing `help printf` in the Bash prompt, 2. reading Bash's man with `man bash`, 3. reading the [online reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-printf).

Comment: Be careful. If your CONFIG_VALUE contains any of the following characters, you'll need to escape them for printf: '%', '\', '\n', '\r', '\t' and a few others.

Comment: @Javon: fixed! `:)`

Answer (score 22):

This uses bash builtins:

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR1="VAR2"

declare "${VAR1}"="value"

echo "VAR1=${VAR1}"
echo "VAR2=${VAR2}"
```

The script output:

```
VAR1=VAR2
VAR2=value
```

Here's the snippet using your variable names:

```
#!/bin/bash

CONFIG_OPTION="VENDOR_NAME"

declare "${CONFIG_OPTION}"="value"

echo "CONFIG_OPTION=${CONFIG_OPTION}"
echo "VENDOR_NAME=${VENDOR_NAME}"
```

The script output:

```
CONFIG_OPTION=VENDOR_NAME
VENDOR_NAME=value
```

Comment: I find the `declare` syntax much easier to read than using `printf`

Comment: but declare is `bash` specific, ergo, not portable.

Comment: I enjoy the use of `printf` in the answer from @gniourf_gniourf, until I saw this answer and remembered this approach, which is much more useful and intuitive for the coders who come after me. :)

Answer (score 4):

For pure shell, possibly try:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

option=vendor_name
value="my vendor"

eval $option="'$value'" # be careful with ', \n, and \ in value
eval echo "\$$option" # my vendor
echo "$vendor_name" # my vendor
```

Why?

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
printf -v "var" "val" # prints the flag, var not set
declare var=val # sh: declare: not found
echo ${!var} # sh: syntax error: bad substitution
```

I don't like eval, but are there any POSIX options?

Answer (score 1):

Existing answers are great for strings, but do not work with arrays.
Here is a working solution for arrays:

```
ARRAY=(a b c d e f)
array_name="ARRAY_NAME"

TARGET_ARRAY="${array_name}[@]"      # ARRAY="ARRAY[@]"
TARGET_ARRAY=("${!TARGET_ARRAY}")    # ARRAY=(a b c d e f)
```

the `array_name` string can also have `*` suffix to obtain the array elements.