# Evaluating "key=value" with whitespaces in "$value" in bash fails

Tags: bash, eval, keyvaluepair

In a script i have a function which evaluates passed 'key=value' parameters, i.e.:

```
function evaluateKeyValuePair() {
    eval "$1"
}

evaluateKeyValuePair "key=value with whitespaces"
evaluateKeyValuePair "key=value"
```

The latter call works fine, "echo $key" prints "value".
However calling the function with whitespaces in "value" does not work: a command-not-found error is thrown for "with" and "whitepaces"

I've already read that using eval generally is a bad idea. But, unfortunately i cannot change the basic layout of the function(s). I just have to live with it.

I tried to change it to:

```
function evaluateKeyValuePair() {

    key="${1%%=*}"
    val2="${1#*"="}"

    eval $key="$val2"
}
```

but this does not work either.

Is there a way to evalute key-pair-values with whitespaces in "value" or do i have to test for whitespaces in the passed parameter and return an error if there are any?

THX in advance!

Comment: This is a bad idea; `bash` already has a way of passing values this way: `key="value with whitespace" ./script` will make `key` available inside `script`. It's not clear what your actual use case is, but this is almost certainly the wrong solution.

Comment: If you're reading all these lines from a file, is there anything else in that file?  Could you just `source` the file instead of trying to process it yourself?

Comment: @chepner: Your suggestion would not work, since some key-value-pairs might be available only after the script has been started or change during runtime.

Comment: @Eric Renouf: Unforunately, there are lines with other key-value-pairs and certain variables must not be overwritten. Indeed, there is a test in the function which checks, if a read-in variable is allowed to be overwritten or not. I just dropped that part here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash, you can perform the assignment using the `declare` built-in, instead of `eval`. This avoids having to insert escaped quotes into the argument.

Note that in a function, `declare` is equivalent to `local` so that it is necessary to add the `-g` (global) flag (implemented in v4.2; prior that that, you would have to use `export` to avoid making the variable local):

```
evaluateKeyValuePair() {
  declare -g "$1"
}
```

Example:

```
$ evaluateKeyValuePair "key=value with whitespaces"
$ echo "$key"
value with whitespaces
```

Comment: "declare -g" is just perfect. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that `declare -g` is only available in `bash` 4.2 or later. Also, `declare` is safer than `eval`, but not entirely safe.

Comment: @chepner: I didn't claim it was safer; only that it requires less attention to quoting. Added the version requirement; thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using single quote

```
function evaluateKeyValuePair() {
    eval "$1"
}

evaluateKeyValuePair 'key="value with whitespaces"'
evaluateKeyValuePair "key=value"
```

You can also escape the double quotes like this :

```
evaluateKeyValuePair "key=\"value with whitespaces\""
```

Comment: Hello Luc! Thanks for your answer. This would not work, since usually the key-vlaue-pairs are read from files. So i would have to transforms the lines into suitable formats and i hoped that would not be necessary. Sometimes the evaluation is needed for user input validation. But you lead me into the right direction: eval $key='$val2' works both for "key=value with whitepaces" and key="value with whitespaces". Thanks a lot for your support!

Answer (score 0):

With your second attempt and the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13717788/4687135) you can do what you want without the eval:

```
function evaluateKeyValuePair() {
    key="${1%%=*}"
    val2="${1#*"="}"

    printf -v $key "$val2"
}

evaluateKeyValuePair "key=value with whitespaces"
printf "%s\n" "$key"
```

which will print `value with whitespaces`