# Construct bash shell variable at run time

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I wanted to construct a variable name as shown below at run time, how can do it in bash shell scripting.

`concatenate_eror_file_user_${instance_name}=echo ${File_User},${concatenate_eror_file_user_${instance_name}}`

Above line gives me an error as `${File_User},${concatenate_eror_file_user_${instance_name}}: bad substitution`
here `instance_name=INST`

`File_User=test`

As `instance_name` and `File_USer` values will be changed in my scripts i am in need of the above mentioned.

Comment: Several errors: First, because of the space after the `echo`, you would assign only the word `echo` to your variable and run the rest of the line as a command. Second, the nesting of the substitiution `${concatenate_eror_file_user_${instance_name}}` is syntactically incorrect. I don't know what you want to achieve; maybe you want `concatenate_eror_file_user` be an associative array and use `$instance_name` as a key?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make clear what you want to achieve. I understand that you have variables `instance_name` and `File_User`. Show example input for both variable,. e.g. `instanceName=TheInstanceName` and `File_User=test`, and expected output matching the example input. What is the resulting variable name you want to construct and what is the expected value of the variable?

Comment: You are basically assigning recursively. You can't say "`x=bob,$x`" and expect anything but a *previous* value to be included.

Comment: when i run the line i will have `concatenate_eror_file_user_INST=test,values of concatenate_eror_file_user_INST` also as i am concatenating `concatenate_eror_file_user_INST` and it will have NULL value hence `concatenate_eror_file_user_INST=test,` is what i expect

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a string variable name from the value of another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716607/creating-a-string-variable-name-from-the-value-of-another-string)